# Каким правилом пунктуации обосновать тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Мне очень нужна консультация преподавателя русского языка. Скажите, пожалуйста: можно ли оставить тире в следующем предложении?

> Тугой капкан морского фронта — не тяжче цéпи холокоста.

Я просто к редакторам обратилась, они тире убрали почему-то. Допустимо ли данное предложение без тире по правилам пунктуации русского языка?

Comment: Вы не указали, что это стихи. Нужна цитата полнее.

Comment: "Тугой капкан морского фронта – не тяжче цéпи холокоста. За алой раной горизонта возник, как гребень, полуостров. Заветный рай, где сны маркизы не верят в ложность зазеркалий. Там дышат небом кипарисы, и тонет май в цветках азалий."    (Более полная цитата)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустимы оба варианта: с тире и без него.
В данном предложении подлежащее (***капкан***) выражено существительным, сказуемое (***не тяжче***) — прилагательным. Чаще всего тире в таких случаях не ставится, но  редакторы, прежде чем убирать его, должны (если есть такая возможность) уточнить у  автора текста его замысел.

Я не преподаватель русского языка. Но правила, регулирующие пунктуацию, а именно постановку [тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92,6#) (справочник Розенталя), гласят:

> 10. Если сказуемое выражено прилагательным (в том числе местоименным) или предложно-именным сочетанием, тире перед сказуемым обычно не ставится: *Погода **несносная**, дорога **скверная**, ямщик **упрямый**...* (П.); *Земля велика и прекрасна* (Ч.); *Вишневый сад **мой**!* (Ч.); *Небо **без** единого **облачка***; *Люди здесь **необыкновенной доброты***.
>     Тире перед сказуемым-прилагательным ставится:
>     **1**) при логическом или интонационном членении предложения: *Зрачки — **кошачьи, длинные*** (Ш.); *Высота возле разбросанных домиков хутора — **командная*** (Каз.).

Таким образом, автор вправе настаивать на постановке тире, тем более при явно выраженной паузе. А если мы увидим "окружение" данного предложения, то можно будет говорить об одном, более приемлемом, варианте.

После информации из комментариев соглашусь с автором этого стихотворного произведения, оформленного нестандартно и, по-моему, очень правильно — как проза. Ритм, интонация, логическое подчеркивание — всё говорит в пользу тире.

Comment: Благодарю Вас, Александр!

Comment: Саша, контекст, по-моему, вот здесь: https://www.chitalnya.ru/work/3026891/. Тугой капкан морского фронта - не тяжче цепи холокоста. За алой раной горизонта возник, как
гребень, полуостров.
Заветный Рай, где сны маркизы не верят в ложность зазеркалий. _Там дышат небом кипарисы, и
тонет май в цветках азалий._ Мечты - как сказки, столь похожи, суть не разнять... Но в крайней мере злой рок не стал меня
тревожить, покуда вышел я на берег. Сады тихи, поля недвижны. Здесь время длило пробудиться.
Уставший Бог дремал, не слышав...
И пели розовые птицы.

Comment: @Лана  После того как Вы привели несколько строк из стихотворения, я бы тоже остановился на варианте с тире. Сам ритм располагает к этому. Подождите другие ответы. А потом сможете выбрать наиболее полезный и принять его (поставить галочку), а также отметить стрелочкой вверх любой полезный Вам ответ. Спасибо за вопрос.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова О как, одновременно написали. А мне почему-то по запросу гугл ничего не предложил...

Comment: Поддержу, поддержу — а как же?! А Вы еще обратите внимание на выделенное мною предложение. Я бы перед "и" не стала бы ставить запятую.

Comment: Точно, согласен: общее **там**. А как вы нашли это красивое стихотворение? Спасибо!

Comment: Обнаружилось на двух сайтах. _Поэмбук_ пишет: "Это стихотворение находится в закрытом доступе". Другой сайт не сразу открылся, а потом еще и не сразу дал доступ. Где-то куда-то что-то нажмалось, и — можно читать. P. S. Может, у нас гугловское обеспечение-разрешение различно? P. P. S. И автора надо поддержать — пусть заходит. Мы творческим натурам всегда рады. Правда?

Comment: Правда, Римма! Поддержите тоже. Мне кажется, Лана и есть автор.

Comment: Римма, я насчёт запятой перед "и" тоже уточняла у специалистов - запятая, судя по всему, допустима.

Comment: Лана, а я "дышащее" предложение ощущаю так: _Там — дышат небом кипарисы и тонет май в цветках азалий._ А можно и а-ля Пушкин: _Там дышат небом кипарисы, там тонет май в цветках азалий._ Или такое оформление не вписывается в Вашу концепцию?

Comment: Римма, всё вписывается. Просто это стихотворение — подарок ко Дню рождения  одному человеку. Хотелось довести его до ума :))

Answer (score 2):

*Тугой капкан морского фронта – не тяжче цéпи холокоста. За алой раной горизонта возник, как гребень, полуостров.*

Могу предложить **интонационный анализ** двух предложений, если интересно.  Как я думаю, для поэтов такой анализ  как раз представляет  интерес.

Итак, правила (как уже было указано) позволяют  автору поставить здесь **интонационное тире.** Но надо ли его ставить, есть ли какой-то более или менее **точный ориентир,** чем внутреннее ощущении ритма? **Да, есть.**

1. **Паузы**, как известно, вещь не очень надежная, хотя правила при постановке тире  ориентируют нас именно на паузы.  Паузы бывают разные – **произносительные** (мы не можем всё читать на одном дыхании) или  **грамматические** разной длительности (они зависят от знака препинания).  В то же время при индивидуальном прочтении люди могут слышать паузы по-разному.
2. Но есть более надежный ориентир – это  **тоническое ударение**, так называется **повышение или понижение** голоса на некоторых ударных слогах в предложении. И вот при постановке тире, кроме  увеличенной паузы, мы **повышаем голос** на одном из слогов  в первой части предложения **перед тире**.
3. **Выбор слова с ударным слогом** зависит от читателя, но обычно им угадывается, причем надо иметь в виду следующее. Если ударение смещать **ближе к началу первой** фразы, то оно слышится особенно **отчетливо** и называется логическим выделением (я бы поставила ударение на слове «капкан»). Что касается автора, то ему нужно в такую ударную позицию поставить нужное слово, тогда  читатель  это почувствует и прочитает верно:  Тугой **капкАн** морского фронта – не тяжче цéпи холокоста.
4. А если **послушать редакторов** и не ставить тире, то что будет? Получится довольно **серенькая интонация** простого предложения, где пауза **произносительная**,  а повышение голоса незаметное и незначительное.
5. Но давайте посмотрим второе предложение: *За алой раной горизонта // возник, как гребень, **полуОстров**.*

В нем мы видим как раз произносительную паузу, а там **другая и не нужна**. Мы не выделяем здесь первую часть, всё наше внимание сосредоточено **на второй части,** а именно на слове «полуостров». Оно выделено понижением голоса в конце предложения (это обычная повествовательная интонация.

6. **Вывод.** В результате получается красивая **ритмика** с нужным **смысловым** содержанием. Так я понимаю эти стихотворные строки, но не знаю, насколько согласен со мной автор. Было бы интересно послушать.

Освоить интонационный анализ просто, там всего-то несколько приемов, но польза будет несомненная, особенно в поэзии.

**Лирическое отступление**

Существует мнение, что о прекрасном можно судить только очень неопределенно и исключительно интуитивно.  **Как это красиво – а дальше что?**  Если много раз повторить или услышать это слово, то понятнее не станет.  Можно ли более точно сказать, что именно красиво, почему красиво.

Поэтому любое восприятие  (интуитивное или рациональное) не стоит отрицать, а **гармонию можно проверить алгеброй** – вспомним хотя бы золотое сечение в архитектуре, золотую пропорцию в музыке, которую вычислил Пифагор.

Вот и **интонацию** можно обозначить более точно, более конкретно, чем просто описать словами. Можно не только интуитивно, но и разумно составлять текст, понимая роль каждого знака и его влияние на произношение, на выразительность речи. Тогда и **в рамках правил**  будете чувствовать себя свободно и уверенно. **Интонационное тире** дает для этого много возможностей, так как для него нет строгой регламентации.

Comment: Красиво!.......

Comment: ... будто берёзка!

Comment: @shampar К кому обращен комментарий и что он означает (надо ставить знак почты)? Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: @shampar Кстати, я не согласна с правкой названия, я могу вернуть прежний вариант? Это не авторское тире, его использование регулируется общим правилом (это ясно из приведенного текста Розенталя). Авторским знаком принято называть ненормированную пунктуацию, когда автор ставит знаки не по правилам.

Comment: Могу (и хотел) взять это слово в кавычки. В любом случае начальная шапка нехороша, т. к. ни о чём не говорила по существу. Потом, о Розентале в вопросе речи нет.

Comment: Мне хотелось бы. чтобы вы вернули прежнее название. Оно носило обобщенный характер, но по существу вопрос был именно о том,  соответствует ли постановка тире обычным правилам.  Авторский знак - это отдельная тема, ее здесь не должно быть вообще. "Необходимость тире - это тоже не очень удачно. Участники в течение всей дискуссии обсуждали эту тему.

Comment: @shampar И верните, пожалуйста, точку за кавычки. Я заметил, что Вы часто ставите ее перед ними, объясняя это тем, что внутри кавычек должны быть все знаки цитаты. Но точка, видимо, исключение и всегда ставится после.

Comment: Не понял, что значит «видимо»... Точка в конце цитаты принадлежит ей и потому не отрывается от неё. Если цитата неполная, то и многоточие.

Comment: Многоточие, !, ? ставятся перед закрывающими кавычками, если принадлежат ей. Точка — исключение. Где Вы видели обратное?

Comment: Цитаты в предложении и отдельные цитаты этим и разнятся. Тут есть табличка, очень наглядная. О знаках (многоточие, !, ?) сказано дополнительно. Точек рядом с условной Ц не увидите, — они есть часть Ц.   https://heaclub.ru/kak-pravilno-oformlyat-citaty-pravilo-primery#i-3м

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрел и прочитал внимательно. Хотя источник и не внушает доверия, всё же первый пример опровергает Ваше видение: *«Люди, которые воспринимают все пустяки близко к сердцу — больше всех способны искренне любить» (Лев Толстой).*